# Which Method is More Practical or Orthodox When Importing Large Data?

Tags: php, api-design

I have a file that has the function of importing data into a sql database from an api. A problem I encountered was that the api can only retrieve a max dataset size of 1000, even though sometimes I need to retrieve large amounts of data, ranging from 10-200,000. My first thought was to create a while loop in which inside I make calls to the api until all of the data is properly retrieved, and afterwards, can I enter it into the database.

```
$moreDataToImport = true;
$lastId = null;
$query = '';

while ($moreDataToImport) {
    $result = json_decode(callToApi($lastId));
    $query .= formatResult($result);
    $moreDataToImport = !empty($result['dataNotExported']);
    $lastId = getLastId($result['customers']);
}
mysqli_multi_query($con, $query);
```

The issue I encountered with this is that I was quickly reaching memory limits. The easy solution to this is to simply increase the memory limit until it was suffice. How much memory I needed, however, was undeclared, because there is always a possibility that I need to import very large datasets, and can theoretically always run out of memory. I don't want to set an infinite memory limit, as the problems with that are unimaginable.
My second solution to this was instead of looping through the imported data, I could instead send it to my database, and then do a page refresh, with a get request specifying the last Id I left off on.

```
if (isset($_GET['lastId'])
    $lastId = $_GET['lastId'];
else
    $lastId = null;
$result = json_decode(callToApi($lastId));
$query .= formatResult($result);
mysqli_multi_query($con, $query);
if (!empty($result['dataNotExported'])) {
    header('Location: ./page.php?lastId='.getLastId($result['customers']));
}
```

This solution solves my memory limit issue, however now I have another issue, being that browsers, after 20 redirects (depends on the browser), will automatically kill the program to stop a potential redirect loop, then shortly refresh the page. The solution to this would be to kill the program yourself at the 20th redirect and allow it to do a page refresh, continuing the process.

```
if (isset($_GET['redirects'])) {
    $redirects = $_GET['redirects'];
    if ($redirects == '20') {
        if ($lastId == null) {
            header("Location: ./page.php?redirects=2");
        }
        else {
            header("Location: ./page.php?lastId=$lastId&redirects=2");
        }
        exit;
    }
}
else
    $redirects = '1';
```

Though this solves my issues, I am afraid this is more impractical than other solutions, as there must be a better way to do this. Is this, or the issue of possibly running out of memory my only two choices? And if so, is one more efficient/orthodox than the other?

Comment: Don't use `mysqli_multi_query()`. It's a PITA to use, and you can't use prepared statements with it.

Answer (score 0):

Do the insert query inside the loop that fetches each page from the API, rather than concatenating all the queries.

```
$moreDataToImport = true;
$lastId = null;
$query = '';

while ($moreDataToImport) {
    $result = json_decode(callToApi($lastId));
    $query = formatResult($result);
    mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $moreDataToImport = !empty($result['dataNotExported']);
    $lastId = getLastId($result['customers']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Page your work.  Break it up into smaller chunks that will be below your memory limit.

If the API only returns 1000 at a time, then only process 1000 at a time in a loop.  In each iteration of the loop you'll query the API, process the data, and store it.  Then, on the next iteration, you'll be using the same variables so your memory won't skyrocket.

A couple things to consider:

1. If this becomes a long running script, you may hit the default script running time limit - so you'll have to extend that with `set_time_limit()`.
2. Some browsers will consider scripts that run *too* long to be timed out and will show the appropriate error message.

For processing upwards of 200,000 pieces of data from an API, I think the best solution is to not make this work dependant on a page load.  If possible, I'd put this in a cron job to be run by the server on a regular schedule.

If the dataset is dependant on the request (for example, if you're processing temperatures from one of 1000s of weather stations - the specific station ID to be set by the user), then consider creating a secondary script that does the work.  Calling and forking the secondary script from your primary script will enable your primary script to finish execution while your secondary script executes in the background on your server.  Something like:

`exec('php path/to/secondary-script.php > /dev/null &');`